# Check if part of a string contains any numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I'm wanting to check if there are any numbers in the address string but only before 'WA' and then set the cleanAddress var based on the result.

How can I get it to only check before 'WA' so the 6000 doesn't cause it to return TRUE.

And potentially different states so check for "WA" or "NSW" or "VIC" etc...

```
const address = "123 Smith, Suburb, WA 6000"
        var cleanAddress = ""

        if(address.match(/^\d+$/)) {
          cleanAddress = ""
         }
         else {
          cleanAddress = ","
         }
```

Expecting

```
"123 Smith, Suburb, WA 6000"    \\result cleanAddress = ""

"Suburb, WA 6000" \\result cleanAddress = ","
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to test for the occurrence, you can use `.test()` and a match without any lookarounds:

```
\d.*?\b(?:WA|NSW|VIC)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\d` Match a digit
- `.*?` Match any character without a newline, as few as possible
- `\b(?:WA|NSW|VIC)\b` Match any of the alternatives between word boundaries

```js
const regex = /\d.*?\b(?:WA|NSW|VIC)\b/;
strings = [
  "123 Smith, Suburb, WA 6000",
  "Suburb, WA 6000"
].forEach(address => {
  let cleanAddress = regex.test(address) ? "" : ","
  console.log(`cleanAddress:'${cleanAddress}'`);
})
```

Comment: Thank you. The look ahead, non capture, word boundaries piece is what I was missing thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

```
const address = "123 Smith, Suburb, WA 6000";
var cleanAddress = "";

// Find the position of 'WA' in the string
var index = address.indexOf("WA");

// Get the part of the string that comes before 'WA'
var substring = address.substring(0, index);

// Use a regular expression to check if the substring contains any numbers
var regex = /\d/;
var containsNumbers = regex.test(substring);

if (containsNumbers) {
  // If the substring contains numbers, set cleanAddress to an empty string
  cleanAddress = "";
} else {
  // If the substring does not contain numbers, set cleanAddress to a comma
  cleanAddress = ",";
}

console.log(cleanAddress);
```

This code first uses the indexOf() and substring() methods to get the part of the string that comes before 'WA'. It then uses a regular expression to check if the substring contains any numbers. If the substring does not contain numbers, the code sets cleanAddress to a comma (,), otherwise it sets cleanAddress to an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex to obtain the number before any check text.

`\b\d+\b(?=.*\bWA)`

[image]

```js
const address = "200 Smith, Suburb, WA 6000"
var cleanAddress = ""

function checkNumberBefore(text, checkText){
  return address.match("\\b\\d+\\b(?=.*\\b" + checkText + ")");
}

var result = checkNumberBefore(address, 'WA');

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for the following pattern:

```
(\d+.+) // One or more digits followed by one or more other characters
(?=(?:WA|NSW|VIC)) // Lookahead to find a (non-capturing group) of possible states
```

```js
const re = /(\d+.+)(?=(?:WA|NSW|VIC))/;

function tester(address, re) {
  return re.test(address) ? '' : '.';
}

console.log(tester('123 Smith, Suburb, WA 6000', re)); // true
console.log(tester('Suburb, VIC 6000', re)); // false
console.log(tester('8 Somewhere Lane, LA 90210', re)); // true
console.log(tester('800 Bob Street, NSW 1000', re)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would highly recommend in this solution is firstly to see what is the pattern to find the section I would like to check. So in your case I see that there are two(2) commas before the 'WA', or if the case is that it would always be WA I would just split it by 'WA', then take the first split element and check if it contains numbers with the regex. Other way around is firstly to find the commas in the regex, then to get through lastindexof function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) and then to slice from the first character to the number of the lastindexof (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and then to use the regex for numbers. Hopefully it would work our for you.